# $x$ln$x$ quadratic approximation at $x=1$

Tags: approximation

> $x$ln$x$ quadratic approximation at $x=1$

2 ways :

1) quadratic approx whole thing :
$(x-1)^2 + \dfrac {(x-1)^2} 2$

This isn't same as
2) split $x$ and take quad approx of ln$x$ at $x=1$

$x((x-1) - \dfrac 1 2 (x-1)^2) = x(2x - \dfrac 3 2)$

Why are they not same?

Comment: Recheck your second simplification. There is an error

Comment: if 1) is the first 2 terms of Taylor series, the first term should be $(x-1)$

Comment: @Shailesh 
$x$(ln $x$) = $x((x-1)-\dfrac {1} {2} (x-1)^2)$  
$= x(x-1 - \dfrac 1 2 x^2 + x - \dfrac 1 2)$   
dropping $x^3$ terms... 
$x(2x-\dfrac 3 2)$

Comment: You can't drop (x -1)^3.  There is an x term and a constant term in there.

Comment: @Shailesh
So I cant drop third term of ln$x$ and onwards? i.e. $(1-x)^4$ and onwards..  

But this is what the solution paper did.. similar but he did this by substituting $x = h + 1$. so approx. at $h = 0$ instead.    

$(1+h)$ ln$(1+h) = (1+h)(h-\dfrac {h^2} 2) = h + \dfrac {h^2} 2$ 
so substituing back gives 1).  

I don't see how this should be different to my second method.. 
He only took quad approx to ln$x$ too

Comment: No. You can only do it when you expand around zero. For all others, the lower terms will always be there and have to be accounted

Comment: Finally made sense and why he used substitution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variable: if $x=1+h$, then
\begin{align*}x\ln x&=(1+h)\ln(1+h)=(1+h)\Bigl(h-\frac{h^2}2+o(h^2)\Bigr)=h+\frac{h^2}2+o(h^2)\\
&=x-1+\frac{(x-1)^2}2+o\bigl((x-1)^2\bigr)=\frac{x^2-1}2+o\bigl((x-1)^2\bigr).
\end{align*}